# I am not able to get sort result for ecommerce website api in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

here is my logic to sort product according to query params pass by user

```
const getAllProduct = asynchandler( async ( req, res)=>{
    try {
        // filter the products search
        const queryObj ={...req.query};
        const excludefield = ["page","short","limit","fields"];// excluding uncessery field from query
        excludefield.forEach((el)=> delete queryObj[el]); 

        let queryString =JSON.stringify(queryObj) // convertig query in string      
        queryString = queryString.replace(/\b(gte|gt|lte|lt)\b/g, (match)=>`$${match}`) // this g will match all the else it will only match 1st
        // console.log(JSON.parse.queryString);
        
        let query = Product.find(JSON.parse(queryString)) // product filterin
       
        // shorting.........
        if (req.query.sort){  
            const sortBy = req.query.sort.split(",").join(" ");
            console.log(sortBy);
            query = query.sort(sortBy) 
        }else{
            query = query.sort('-createdAt')
           console.log("else sort by createdAt")
        }
        const product = await query;
        res.json(product)
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error)
    }
})
```

but i'm getting empty array as response

here is my api request : localhost:5000/api/product/?sort=category,brand

I'm  looking for product sorted in according to category

Answer (score 0):

There are many many problems, i had to rewrite most of it.
Some points:

`find()` returns a cursor you need to await toArray();

To order you need to send an object with 1 for ascending and -1 for descending order like this: `{brand: 1}`

The argument to `find()` in the filter not the sorting, you were passing the sort to the find

To filter i added a param "filter" in the query like this:

http://localhost:5000/api/product/?sort=category,brand,limit&filter=name:red,size:big

You need to define everything and use all at once, find().sor()

Considering this collection:

```
[

    {
        _id: ObjectId(),
        "category": 'Food',
        "brand": 'Two',
        "createdAt": ISODate(),
        "name": "Pink Grape",
        "size": "small"
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId(),
        "category": 'Food',
        "brand": 'One',
        "createdAt": ISODate(),
        "name": "Red Apple",
        "size": "big"
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId(),
        "category": 'Car',
        "brand": 'Zuui',
        "createdAt": ISODate(),
        "name": "Yellow Car",
        "size": "big"
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId(),
        "category": 'Car',
        "brand": 'Aoim',
        "createdAt": ISODate(),
        "name": "Blue Car",
        "size": "medium"
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId(),
        "category": 'Car',
        "brand": 'Two',
        "createdAt": ISODate(),
        "name": "Red Car",
        "size": "small"
    }

]
```

and this route:

```
app.get("/api/product/", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const sortFields = req.query.sort?.split(',').filter(field => !["page", "short", "limit", "fields"].includes(field));
        let sortObj = {};
        sortFields?.forEach(field => sortObj[field] = 1);

        if (!req.query.sort) {
            sortObj = ({ createdAt: 1 });
        }

        const filters = req.query.filter?.split(',');
        let filterObj = {}
        filters?.forEach(filter => {
            const key = filter.split(":")[0];
            const value = filter.split(":")[1];
            filterObj[key] = { $regex: value, $options: 'i' }
        });

        const products = await Product.find(filterObj).sort(sortObj).toArray();
        res.json(products)
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error)
    }
})
```

Comment: I don't want to use limit just want to sort base on brand and category... any suggestion for that....

Comment: It's already in the code, it's being removed page, short, limit and Fields, `sortFields = ...`

Comment: Or you can change the array to be only Brand and category and remove the negation `!`